# How is the Students Paying Down Debt field calculated in the College Scorecard website?

Tags: collegescorecard

How is the Students Paying Down Debt field calculated in the College Scorecard website? I don't see a field in the data dictionary that precisely corresponds to it, nor even a set of fields that could.

Comment: This is not an answer but rather a follow up question. Is this really within 3 years of leaving school? Or 3 years after entering repayment? At community colleges, students leave and go on to enroll at other community colleges. If it is within 3 years of leaving school, is the ED then looking at enrollment data to determine there has been no continuous enrollment within those 3 years?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the consumer website, you can click the "i" button below the "Students Paying Down Debt Field" on each college page and it will display a brief definition for the measure. It should also correspond to the 3-year repayment rate field on the more technical website at collegescorecard.ed.gov/data

The short definition for this measure is: The share of students who have repaid at least $1 of the principal balance on their federal loans within 3 years of leaving school.